# luggage and immigration

Tags: customs-and-immigration, luggage, layovers, nrt

I will be travelling from Cebu, Philippines to Vancouver, Canada witha 4 hour layover at Narita International airport in Japan. I will fly Pal to Narita then American Airlines to Vancouver both are located at terminal 2
Questions:
1 - Can i have my luggage checked right through or must i retrieve it and submit to 2nd carrier ?
2 - do i have to clear Customs and Immigration at Narita ?

thanx

Comment: Did you book two separate tickets for this, one with PAL from Cebu to Narita and another with American from Narita to Vancouver? I don't believe they are partners.